# How to call ajax and console.log to debugger it in apify puppeteer crawler?

Tags: apify

I have a website that calls ajax load more data when clicking a button.
In this case, I'm using ajax to call load more data.
It's the same with pagination.
My code is follows:

```
function callAj(page) {
    context.log.info('load page : ' + page);
    // This log can show when I run the task.
    fetch("url", {
        "headers": {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "accept-language": "vi,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        },
        "body": "action=load_more&sid=6&cid=9&orderby=date&order=DESC&size=9&ex=false" + "&pg=" + page,
        "method": "POST"
    }).then(res => res.text())
    .then(data => { 
      if (data != '') {
          // This log can't show when I run the task.
          context.log.info('data in here can't not show: ' + data);
          $('#id').append(data); page++; callAj(page);
      }
    })
}
```

When I call ajax in console of chrome developer, it still works well. But in Apify I can't run it
How to resolve it?

Comment: Can you give me more information why you can't run it? In Web Scraper (pageFunction is in the browser context), it should work out of the box. Ideally, I would make everything async/await, it is much more clean

Outside of Web Scraper, you need to run it inside Puppeteer's page.evaluate()

Answer (score 0):

The full code is here in my task:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const $ = context.jQuery;

    function callAj(page) {
        context.log.info('load page : ' + page);
        fetch("url", {
            "headers": {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "accept-language": "vi,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            },
            "body": "action=load_more&sid=6&cid=9&orderby=date&order=DESC&size=9&ex=false" + "&pg=" + page,
            "method": "POST"
        }).then(res => res.text())
        .then(data => { if (data != ''){context.log.info(`data: ${data}`);$('#id').append(data); page++; callAj(page);}})
    }

    callAj(1);

    var codes = [];
    var industryContents = [];
    var results = {};
    $(".offers-details").each(function(i, e){
        if ($(e).find('.coupon-code').length > 0) {
            codes.push($(e).find('.coupon-code .btn-copy').attr('data-clipboard-text'));
            industryContents.push($(e).find('div.polyxgo_title div:last-child').text());
        }
    });
    // $('.coupon-code .btn-copy').get().forEach((e) => codes.push($(e).attr('data-clipboard-text')));
    // $(".offers-details div.polyxgo_title > div:nth-child(6)").get().forEach((e) => industryContents.push($(e).text()));
    codes.map((e, i) => {
        results[e] = industryContents[i];
    })
    context.log.info(`code: ${codes}`);
    context.log.info(`industryContent: ${industryContents}`);
    context.log.info(results);
    return results;
}
```

After I run it, I can't receive enough results.